# Why is Logger<MyClass> not automatically available as DI service

Tags: c#, .net, logging, .net-core, dependency-injection

When trying to instantiate

```
public class MyClass : BackgroundService {
  private ILogger<MyClass> Logger {get;}
  public MyClass(Logger<MyClass> logger) {
    Logger = logger
  }
}
```

through .Net DI by registering `MyClass` through

```
services.AddHostedService<MyClass>();
```

When the class is activated, an exception is thrown:

> `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1[MyClass]' while attempting to activate 'MyClass'.'`

I understood that `ILogger<T>` should be automatically available for all types `T`.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `ILogger<T>` is automatically available, `Logger<T>` isn't.

Change the constructor parameter from `Logger<MyClass>` to `ILogger<MyClass>` and then everything should work.